# 'Access is Denied' error when configuring Visual Studio for debugging

Tags: c, windows, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to run some code on VS Express 2013 for Desktop it says that the project is out of date. When I searched for solutions they told me to search for devenv.exe.config but it wasn't there for me so I guessed WDExpress.exe.config was the correct one. I opened it up and pasted in:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="CPS" value="4" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

That didn't help so I pasted in:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="CPS" switchName="CPS" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="cpsFileLogger"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="CPS" value="Warning"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="cpsFileLogger" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\devenv-cps.log">
            <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Warning"/>
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

They were both pasted in after . The second block I found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx
Whenever I try to save the file, it says some form of access denied. I also downloaded DebugView but it didn't capture anything. When I try to tick "Capture Global Win32" it says access denied. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Right click "Run as administrator"

Comment: Run VS/Notepad as administrator?

Answer (score 4):

The config file you're editing is located in the `Program Files` folder, which will have UAC restrictions on it. You need to run your editor as Administrator in order to have the correct permissions needed to save the changes to the file system.

Comment: Well I've done this but from what other people say, the debugger doesn't say anything about:
devenv.exe Information: 0 : Project 'Bla\Bla\Dummy.vcxproj' not up to date because build input 'Bla\Bla\SomeFile.h' is missing.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem from what you've described.  What you've asked about is how to change the .config file for the Visual Studio executable itself, not your program.  It sounds like you've got a compilation error in your code and as a result you're debugging an .exe that's older than your source code.

Comment: I tried to change the config file so as to allow the DebugView program to check for error in VS I think. But it doesn' t show anything that people with this error have got. I'm pretty shure my code is correct though.